# Signing Soap request with certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, soap

I'd like to sign a Soap request (.NET 3.5, C#) with a certificate stored in the computer (reading of certificate is ok).

I don't want the request to be encrypted (that's what I get when I change `Security.Mode` and `Security.Message` properties on `WSHttpBinding`). **I am looking for a signed Soap header**.

After reading tons of articles on MSDN, blog, StackOverflow... I came up with this approach: using `IClientMessageInspector` and method `BeforeSendRequest`. I can set a breakpoint in it and see my request, but how to [modify its XML content](http://forums.asp.net/t/1579836.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the message is possible - for sample code and explanations see

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/ExtendingWCF_PartI.aspx
- http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/iclientmessageinspector/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx

Basically you copy the `Message` to an XML Doc as a buffered copy, modify the XML, then create a new `Message` from that modified XML and assign the new `Message` to the `ref Message` param...

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure this is the right way (modifing by hand the XML),  but it answers my question :)

Comment: first link takes to some scamming (you have won a price) site.